# Git add . does add files listed in .gitignore

Tags: git, gitignore

I want to stop tracking certain files in Git that I've added to the `.gitignore` file.

I used `git rm --cached` (and also tried `git rm -r --cached .`) but after running `git add .`, a `git commit --dry-run` tells me the files in my gitignore are "to be committed".

The contents of the `.gitignore` file are:

```
/source/backup/*
/site/index.php
/site/userscript.user.js
```

**What's wrong with this gitignore?**

Things were working just fine when the only line was `source/backup/*`. As soon as I added the second line, the `source/backup/*` files are getting committed as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Clear out your index.

```
git reset
```

Stop tracking files in your backup folder.

```
git rm --cached source/backup/
```

Commit this change by itself.

```
git commit -m "Removing backup folder from git."
```

Proceed normally. Ignored files should not accidentally slip in at this point provided your ignore file is setup properly. I'd recommend preceding it with a slash (assuming that folder exists in the root of your repository).

```
#.gitignore
/source/backup/
/site/index.php
```

Open up YouTube. Master git. http://youtu.be/ZDR433b0HJY

Comment: After these steps, I still get the backup files after I do a `git add .`. It is the intention that you cannot `git add` gitignored files right? I'll update the original question with the latest gitignore.

Comment: Get rid of that asterisk. I don't know if it causes any harm here, but all my ignore files just refer to the path (as my example indicates in my post), and I know they are working.

Comment: I missed that you removed the `*`. Removing that one plus adding the initial \ did the trick. Thanks a bunch, been busy with this one for a few hours :).

Comment: I just got around watching the youtube movie: Excellent presentation! Thanks for sharing. Am hardly a 'master' now but at least I have some idea of what I'm doing.

Comment: @Laoujin Yeah, it's a great video. I recommend it to anyone I run into working with git.